# jQuery .each() setting variable to the first one it finds

Tags: jquery, each

I'm trying to loop through all of the .starwrapper divs on a page, then find some text inside of that div and then add it to be displayed at the end of the div.

Like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.starwrapper').each(function( index ) {
      var starvalue = $('.starwrapper .rating').text();
      $(this).children('.star-rating').append(starvalue);
    });
});
</script>
```

Trouble is, every one of them gets the first starvalue variable's value. Might anyone know what I'm doing wrong with that .each()?

Comment: Please post your html

Comment: `$('.starwrapper .rating').text()` always gets the value of the first one. It's doing exactly what you coded it to do. Being inside of a `.each` doesn't change what the methods do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that this line:

```
var starvalue = $('.starwrapper .rating').text();
```

Is effectively absolute, it searches for all `.starwrapper` elements, not taking `$this` into account.

Try this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.starwrapper').each(function( index ) {
      var starvalue = $(this).find('.rating').text();
      $(this).children('.star-rating').append(starvalue);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to find the text from the current element `$(this)` and not globally, so try to replace

`var starvalue = $('.starwrapper .rating').text();`

with

`var starvalue = $(this).find('.rating').text();`

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure but try this for starvalue variable:

```
var starvalue = $('.rating', $(this)).text();
```

Comment: Who downvoted and why? :) Please explain what's the problem with this. It's the optimised way of previous answers.